# How to apply the configuration in Spring to not create session for mobile app calls?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5 with Spring Security for a web application. Everything is working great but now we want to launch a mobile app.

For this, we want to use the existing web application for the API server, the only difference would be that we will create a few REST endpoints in the app.

From my research, I have come to the conclusion to use OAuth2 for authentication purposes and use a JWT token to access the information from these endpoints.

My question is: how to make sure the Spring doesn't create any sessions for these REST requests in Spring? I know I could use

```java
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

at the application level but that would make the whole configuration stateless, which we don't want because the same app supports the web platform.

Comment: It will only make security stateless not the rest, that setting doesn't prevent you from using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

REST APIs secured with access tokens are resource servers. It is usually configured as stateless (the security context is build from the access token, not from session), which has nice benefits when thinking of scalability and fault tolerance, but resource servers are queried by OAuth2 clients.

Unfortunately, mobile applications make unsafe OAuth2 clients (it can only be "public" clients when [Spring Security team now recommends to use "confidential" clients only](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390)).

So having session based security seems a rather good idea for whatever is facing the mobile application.

If you want to keep a monolith, then just don't try to make your app (or even part of it) a resource server with JWT.

If you opt for a distributed architecture (one app serving MVC UI, another being a REST API configured as resource server), then you may configure a `spring-cloud-gateway` as Backend For Frontend for your mobile app (as an OAuth2 client with `TokenRelay` filter).

In any case, when securing a mobile app with sessions in an OAuth2 flow, you have to make sure that the authorization-code is provided to the OAuth2 client by the same user agent (HTTP client) as the one it will use to send the REST requests needing to be authorized.

This means that you should provide a deep link (Android app link or iOS universal link) as redirection URI when initiating the `authorization_code` flow in the system browser and intercept the answer with the authorization-code to return this code with the application inner HTTP client (the tokens the OAuth2 client will get with this code, will be stored in the session tied to the user agent sending the code, so you want it to be the app HTTP client and not the system browser).

Comment: Thanks for providing context. So if I want to use monolith and provide json responses to mobile apps via REST calls, how would that flow work? app user does the login, spring creates a session for the mobile app, mobile app stores the jsessionID, keeps calling based on the jsessionID?

Comment: The app redirects the user to the authorization-endpoint using the system browser (user leaves the app) at URI containing a callback URI as request param (the deep link). User logs-in as normal on the authorization server. The authorization responds with a 302 to the callback URI (we are still in the browser). The user device routes this callback URI to the app (because it is a deep link). The app forwards the callback to the Spring OAuth2 client using its own HTTP client.

Comment: Rest of the flow as normal, Spring exchanges the authorization code for tokens and store it in the session. The next requests coming from the same user agent (the mobile app HTTP client) should be authorized (which won't happen if you let all the flow run in the system browser: the authorized session will be one tied to the system browser, not to the app HTTP client).